# apex:outputlink unable to show content of record on mouse hover in lightning

Tags: lightning, mini-page-layout

gone through [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60434/can-i-get-the-mini-layout-hover-to-appear-on-any-link-like-it-does-for-outputfi) link for using apex:outputLink to show salesforce mini layout in classic view.

trying to do similar thing in Lightning view but unable to find a way out.

is there any way to show salesforce mini layout on hover in lightning view.

In my use case, i'm using anchor tag to show record link.

On hover of anchor tag, I want to show salesforce MINI layout for my custom or standard object.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DdKpQAK). It might help.

It refers to the similar problem that you are facing. It shows a way without writing code.